Plural oder Singular?
Was ist hier korrekt?

Alles, was du hören kannst, ist Lydias ratterndes Schnarchen und Martins Daumenkuppen, die gegen die Joystickknöpfe drücken

oder

Alles, was du hören kannst, sind Lydias ratterndes Schnarchen und Martins Daumenkuppen, die gegen die Joystickknöpfe drücken.


Möglicherweise geht es bei der Frage um die Zusammenfassung (Schnarchen und Daumenkuppen), aber tatsächlich ist eines der beiden Dinge, nämlich die Daumenkuppen, schon im Plural und deshalb muß dort auf jeden Fall ein Plural hin:

Alles, was du hören kannst, ist [...] Daumenkuppen

Das wäre definitiv falsch. Das Sprachgefühl schreit wohl nur deshalb nicht auf, weil zwischen dem Plural und dem "ist" noch etwas im Singular steht und dieser Zusammenhang verdeckt wird. Dreht man zum Vergleich aber die Aufzählung um (Daumenkuppen zuerst, Schnarchen danach), dann merkt man, daß die Formulierung hinkt.

Alles, was du hören kannst, sind Martins Daumenkuppen, die gegen die Joystickknöpfe drücken und Lydias ratterndes Schnarchen.

Hier würde sich alles gegen "ist" statt "sind" sträuben. Aus dem Grund: ausschließlich "sind" ist richtig.

Nachtrag: @JonathanHerrera hat in einem Kommentar eingewandt, daß das Subjekt "alles" im Singular stehe. Das ist zwar richtig, aber das Indefinitpronomen "alles" hat eine Doppelnatur: steht es für eine (unzählbare) Menge, dann verlangt es auch den Singular:

Alles (das) ist richtig.

hingegen kann es für zählbare Pluralitäten stehen und in dem Falle ist der Plural notwendig:

Das alles sind richtige Erkenntnisse.

Im angegebenen Beispiel bezieht sich "alles" nun auf eine einzelne Sache (das Schnarchen) und eine solche Pluralität. Schon zweiteres würde den Plural verlangen, die Zusammenfassung bedingt diesen erst recht - und zwar unabhängig von der Verwendung von "alles":

Schlafen und Essen sind meine liebsten Beschäftigungen.

Versuchsweise hier ein "ist" zu ersetzen klingt jedenfalls in meinen Ohren grundfalsch. Das geht nur, wenn sich die Aussage ausdrücklich auf eines bezieht:

Schlafen oder Essen ist meine liebste Auswahl.


Man könnte sich auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass das Subjekt Alles ist und Singular.

Schlüssig. Besten Dank

@JonathanHerrera: Das alles ist richtig, aber wenn mit "alles" eine zählbare Pluralität ausgedrückt wird, dann nimmt man trotzdem den Plural: das alles sind Dinge, die unser Sprachgefühl für richtig hält. Das "das alles" im zweiten Fall ist eigentlich ein "diese alle".

Klingt plausibel. Jedoch ist das Relativpronomen im Beispielsatz ja nun gerade im Singular. Das spricht in meinen Augen dafür, Alles als Singular zu behandeln. Ich kenne mich nicht aus, ich versuche nur, das zu verstehen, und deine Antwort lässt diese Fragen für mich offen.

Wenn eine Reihung mit einer Nominalphrase in dieser Stellung im Singular beginnt, möchte ich meinen, darf man den Singular nutzen. Im "Normalfall" erfordert eine Reihung natürlich Plural.
Nr. 1606 in der Duden-Grammatik (2011), "Einfluss der Wortstellung"..
Dass das dem Sprachgefühl entspricht, zeigt zumindest Bakunin in seiner Antwort.
Rein gefühlstechnisch ist für mich der Plural falsch.

Vom Gefühl her eindeutig. Aber bakunins Antwort lässt mich dann doch zum Plural neigen. Am besten ist wohl, man schreibt den Satz um...
